# SG3524 for Mosfet gate driver

Tags: voltage-regulator, pwm

I want to use [SG3524](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sg2524.pdf) for generating a PWM signal of 200kHz frequency to be provided at the common base for the two complementary transistors [SS8050](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/SS8050-117753.pdf) & SS8550. This is to be a gate driver circuit for a mosfet used as a switch in a Buck converter.

How do I proceed after selecting R and C values?

Comment: which RC values?

Comment: Don't use a 1977 IC for something that can be cheaper to buy as a modern buck IC, with far lower losses, better rise times, better control, less pins, no need for external MOSFET gate driving BJTs... Honestly, the SG3524 as design approach would earn you a "no, go redesign that with a different component" as a review. Also, I'm less than thrilled about your choice of transistors; these are low-gain, thus slow-switching in conjunction with your 1977 driver.

Comment: Post a schematic also.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do we need a Retro EE site like Retrocomputing.SE for questions like this, 8086, LM741 and valves?

Comment: @BrianDrummond and 555 as switching regulator becase some fritzling diagram was found on some forum!

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The RT and CT components.

Comment: @winny I think there's some ML enthusiast that could design and train a DNN to  generate random Fritzing diagrams for random instructables, and it would be really hard to tell what the real ones and what the generated ones are.

Comment: @MarcusMuller That’s the evilest thing I can imagine. :-)